# Error upgrading to 6.1 Worklight Developer in RAD 9.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, ibm-rational

I have a brand new RAD 9.0 installed with Worklight Studio 6.0.0.2, and, I'm trying to upgrade to 6.1.1, but, getting the error:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: IBM Worklight Studio 6.1.0.01-20140311-2356 (com.ibm.imp.tools.feature.feature.group 6.1.0.01-20140311-2356)
  Missing requirement: Worklight Project Upgrader Plugin 1.0.0.00-20140309-1625 (com.worklight.upgrader.plugin 1.0.0.00-20140309-1625) requires 'package org.apache.commons.lang [2.5.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM Worklight Studio 6.1.0.01-20140311-2356 (com.ibm.imp.tools.feature.feature.group 6.1.0.01-20140311-2356)
    To: com.worklight.upgrader.feature.feature.group 1.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Worklight Project Upgrader 1.0.0.00-20140309-1625 (com.worklight.upgrader.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.00-20140309-1625)
    To: com.worklight.upgrader.plugin [1.0.0.00-20140309-1625]

I'm running on Mac OSX.  Surely WL 6.1 is compatible with RAD 9?

**UPDATE AFTER INSTALLING 9.0.1 RAD:**

Still getting an error, slightly different, here:

Your original request has been modified.
  "IBM Dojo Mobile Tools" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
  "IBM jQuery Mobile Tools" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
  "IBM Worklight Studio" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: IBM jQuery Mobile Tools 6.1.0.01-20140311-2356 (com.ibm.webtools.jquery.tools.licensed.feature.feature.group 6.1.0.01-20140311-2356)
  Missing requirement: Worklight Project Upgrader Plugin 1.0.0.00-20140309-1625 (com.worklight.upgrader.plugin 1.0.0.00-20140309-1625) requires 'package org.apache.commons.lang [2.5.0,3.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM Worklight Studio 6.1.0.01-20140311-2356 (com.ibm.imp.tools.wce.feature.feature.group 6.1.0.01-20140311-2356)
    To: com.worklight.studio.feature.feature.group 6.1.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM jQuery Mobile Tools 6.1.0.01-20140311-2356 (com.ibm.webtools.jquery.tools.licensed.feature.feature.group 6.1.0.01-20140311-2356)
    To: com.ibm.imp.tools.wce.feature.feature.group 6.1.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM Worklight Studio 6.1.0.01-20140311-2356 (com.worklight.studio.feature.feature.group 6.1.0.01-20140311-2356)
    To: com.worklight.studio.plugin [6.1.0.01-20140311-2356]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: WorklightStudioPlugin 6.1.0.01-20140311-2356 (com.worklight.studio.plugin 6.1.0.01-20140311-2356)
    To: bundle com.worklight.upgrader.plugin 0.0.0

Comment: I have ran the same test and you are right, there is indeed a compatibility issue. I have requested an official fix for this problem; please contact the IBM support for further assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should now be fixed in the Worklight 6.1.0.1 ifix, dated 20140418. You can download the latest Developer Edition from Eclipse Marketplace or get the [Consumer](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFix?product=ibm/Other%20software/IBM%20Worklight%20Consumer%20Edition&fixids=6.1.0.1-WCE-IF201404180637&source=dbluesearch&function=fixId&parent=ibm/Other) or [Enterprise](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm/Other%2bsoftware&product=ibm/Other%20software/IBM%20Worklight%20Enterprise%20Edition&release=6.1.0.1&platform=All&function=all) ifix from Fixcentral.

Answer (score 3):

RAD 9.0 will work fine with Worklight Studio 6.0.
However for Worklight Studio 6.1 you will need RAD 9.0.1. Previous versions do not have all the correct versions for the pre-requisites.

You may find more information about RAD updates on IBM [Fix Central](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~Rational&product=ibm/Rational/IBM%20Rational%20Application%20Developer%20for%20WebSphere%20Software&release=9.0.0&platform=All&function=all).

**EDIT: The current WL Studio v6.1.0.1 P2 installer has a compatibility issue with RAD v9.0.1.** 
This is a defect, the two products are supposed to work together and the development team is already working on a fix. Please feel free to contact IBM support and request a *TestFix* while the official fix is not released yet. Thanks to @DavidW for pointing this out.