# How to update Worklight Studio to version 6.1.0.1

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, rad, worklight-studio

I'm using RAD 9.0.1, and Worklight Studio 6.1.0.

Recently downloaded WL 6.1 Fixpack 001 which contained P2 repository with Worklight Studio 6.1.0.1.

Now I can't install it, because it says that I already have Worklight Studio installed.

On the other hand I can't uninstall it: the option is disabled.

It's catch 22.

See the screenshot:

[image: can't uninstall]
[image: can't install]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was managed to update RAD 9.0.1 with Studio 6.1.0.1, with some warnings and errors, but finally seems it doing what I need.

Here are my steps:

1) Unzip the P2 repository to folder.

2) Add the folder in RAD via **Window > Preferences > Install/Update**

3) Goto **Help > Check for Updates**

4) RAD recognized Worklight Studio updates, but they were read only due to some insufficient privileges problems (I'm using Windows 7, as user), see the screenshot:

[image: insufficient privileges problem]

5) Then I exited RAD and right clicked RAD icon and selected "Run as administrator".

6) Worklight Studio 6.1.0.1 update installed successfully. Exited from RAD running under administrator.

7) Started RAD as regular user - waited long time, hard disk working heavily, but finally RAD opened with warnings/errors that WL 6.1.0 plugin not found.

8) Exited and re-run RAD again as user, second time started normally and without errors, see the screen:

[image: Installed software in RAD 9]

**UPDATE:** Still continue receiving these messages in RAD's Console View, maybe it's not serious:

```
[2014-04-30 11:29:32]             The bundle "com.ibm.etools.rpe.worklight_1.0.400.v20131126_0602 [1883]" could not be resolved. Reason: Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.etools.rpe.worklight_1.0.400.v20140311_2325, Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.etools.rpe.worklight_1.0.400.v20140311_2325
[2014-04-30 11:29:33]             The bundle "com.ibm.imp.worklight.core_6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 [1888]" could not be resolved. Reason: Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.imp.worklight.core_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356, Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.imp.worklight.core_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356
[2014-04-30 11:29:33]             The bundle "com.ibm.imp.worklight.dojo.core_6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 [1889]" could not be resolved. Reason: Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.imp.worklight.dojo.core_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356, Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.imp.worklight.dojo.core_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356
[2014-04-30 11:29:33]             The bundle "com.ibm.imp.worklight.dojo.ui_6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 [1890]" could not be resolved. Reason: Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.imp.worklight.dojo.ui_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356, Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.imp.worklight.dojo.ui_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356
[2014-04-30 11:29:33]             The bundle "com.ibm.imp.worklight.ipas_6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 [1891]" could not be resolved. Reason: Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.imp.worklight.ipas_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356, Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.imp.worklight.ipas_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356
[2014-04-30 11:29:33]             The bundle "com.ibm.imp.worklight.simulation.ui_6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 [1892]" could not be resolved. Reason: Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.imp.worklight.simulation.ui_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356, Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.imp.worklight.simulation.ui_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356
[2014-04-30 11:29:33]             The bundle "com.ibm.imp.worklight.ui_6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 [1893]" could not be resolved. Reason: Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.imp.worklight.ui_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356, Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.imp.worklight.ui_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356
[2014-04-30 11:29:33]             The bundle "com.ibm.worklight.editors_6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 [2341]" could not be resolved. Reason: Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.worklight.editors_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356, Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.worklight.editors_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356
[2014-04-30 11:29:33]             The bundle "com.ibm.worklight.ngn.common_6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 [2342]" could not be resolved. Reason: Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.worklight.ngn.common_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356, Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.worklight.ngn.common_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356
[2014-04-30 11:29:33]             The bundle "com.ibm.worklight.ngn.editor_6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 [2343]" could not be resolved. Reason: Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.worklight.ngn.editor_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356, Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.worklight.ngn.editor_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356
[2014-04-30 11:29:33]             The bundle "com.ibm.worklight.ngn.rpe_6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 [2345]" could not be resolved. Reason: Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.worklight.ngn.rpe_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356, Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.worklight.ngn.rpe_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356
[2014-04-30 11:29:33]             The bundle "com.ibm.worklight.ngn.runtime.dojo_6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 [2346]" could not be resolved. Reason: Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.worklight.ngn.runtime.dojo_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356, Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.worklight.ngn.runtime.dojo_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356
[2014-04-30 11:29:33]             The bundle "com.ibm.worklight.ngn.services_6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 [2347]" could not be resolved. Reason: Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.worklight.ngn.services_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356, Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.worklight.ngn.services_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356
[2014-04-30 11:29:33]             The bundle "com.ibm.worklight.ngn.services.sap_6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 [2348]" could not be resolved. Reason: Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.worklight.ngn.services.sap_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356, Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.worklight.ngn.services.sap_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356
[2014-04-30 11:29:33]             The bundle "com.ibm.worklight.ngn.services.wsdl_6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 [2349]" could not be resolved. Reason: Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.worklight.ngn.services.wsdl_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356, Another singleton version selected: com.ibm.worklight.ngn.services.wsdl_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356
[2014-04-30 11:29:33]             The bundle "com.worklight.worklight-3rd-parties_6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 [2352]" could not be resolved. Reason: Another singleton version selected: com.worklight.worklight-3rd-parties_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356, Another singleton version selected: com.worklight.worklight-3rd-parties_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356
[2014-04-30 11:29:36]             can't create folder:C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\plugins\com.worklight.studio.plugin_6.1.0.01-20140311-2356\liberty\wlp\etc
```

Answer (score 1):

This should now be fixed in the latest 6.1.0.1 ifix (IF20140418 datestamp). How recent was your update? If you aren't at that level and you are using Developer Edition, pull the latest from Eclipse Marketplace. If you have a paid edition, get the latest from Fixcentral [Consumer Edition](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFix?product=ibm/Other%20software/IBM%20Worklight%20Consumer%20Edition&fixids=6.1.0.1-WCE-IF201404180637&source=dbluesearch&function=fixId&parent=ibm/Other) or [Enterprise Edition](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm/Other%2bsoftware&product=ibm/Other%20software/IBM%20Worklight%20Enterprise%20Edition&release=6.1.0.1&platform=All&function=all).

Comment: Hi can check what level it is? The file I have (from FIxCentral) is  **271 075 438** bytes, name **6.1.0-WL-StudioP2-FP0001.zip**

Comment: @Barat, that looks like the 6.1.0.1 Fixpack (FP is the code for fixpacks). Fixpacks are major fix updates. In between fixpacks, Worklight provides smaller ifixes (IF is the code, as in IF20140418). You will want to want to upgrade your fixpack level code with the latest ifix. Follow the info above to get the latest ifix.

Comment: I see some new ifix at the link you posted:  6.1.0.1-WCE-IF201404271450. Also, how can I check what edition I have installed? How they differ?

Comment: See this: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27036358  and this: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/getstart/c_wl_editions.html

Answer (score 0):

See this question with a similar question: [Error upgrading to 6.1 Worklight Developer in RAD 9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813368/error-upgrading-to-6-1-worklight-developer-in-rad-9-0)

From the answer to the question:

> The current WL Studio v6.1.0.1 P2 installer has a compatibility issue
>   with RAD v9.0.1.  This is a defect, the two products are supposed to
>   work together and the development team is already working on a fix.

If this is important for you, you can open a PMR requesting a tempfix while the development team is working on a fix.